# Eclipse Python debugging

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I need your help.

I'm currently help two graduate students begin their first footsteps into programming, and I've suggested Python.  One went straight for Eclipse, since she had seen me using it, and we decided just to catch the other student up with the same setup.  Here's the issue.  Both downloaded Eclipse Luna, both used Eclipse's option to download new data for installing pydev from http://pydev.org/updates

Only one debugger works.  When starting the pydev debugger, usually Eclipse puts a line in the console such as 'pydev debugger: starting' then it jumps to the debug perspective.  For one student on starting the debugging process the console outputs:

'pydev debugger: starting (pid: 4024)'
'\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 2183, in '

and does not move onto the debugging perspective.

I have never came across this before, and my two days of searching for answers has come to nothing.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse only switches to the debug perspective when it hits a breakpoint.

Try to enable the option "Stop in main" (it should be on the first tab of the Debug launch config dialog). Python will then prepare everything but wait for Eclipse's debugger to connect before it starts the program.

Alternatively, set a breakpoint in the source. Eclipse should offer you to switch to the debug perspective when it is hit.

Lastly, check the preferences for `Run/Debug -> Launching`. There, you can enable/disable whether Eclipse should automatically switch to the Debug perspective or ask or not do anything.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the answer.  I had used a break point on the first variable declaration, but i'll try the launching preferences.  I did look through a few menu's but couldn't find anything at the time that looked responsible, but the "Stop in main" is also a another good tip.  Thanks very much.